# Broken links in old answers

Tags: support

Today I came across [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31879/are-there-other-nice-math-books-close-to-the-style-of-tristan-needham), and noticed that the link given in the first answer was broken in a funny way. The link was given as plain text, and the system automatically converted it to a clickable link, with a destination URL of the form `rads.stackoverflow.net/amzn/click/...` that did not work (even the root rads.stackoverflow.net page is not accessible). I fixed that one manually, but there are other answers with similar problems.

For example, the one by Pratik Deoghare also has one of those weird links. However, try to edit it and everything looks fine in the preview window. Until you save the edit, that is, when `rads.stackoverflow.net/amzn/click/...` reappears.

The other answers to the same question that are affected by this issue are Adrian Petrescu's, Per Vognsen's, Hans Lundmark's, David Corwin's, John D. Cook's, Alfred Inselberg's and Rune's.

I suppose this is something that occurred during migration, and I guess that other links in other questions suffer from the same problem. Does anybody know that happened and how to fix it?

**Edit:** a little online research uncovered [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/) at the StackExchange Blog, which says

> we now auto-insert Stack Overflow affiliate info into any amazon book links posted on Stack Overflow

I can confirm that the answer I edited is converted such an "affiliate link", but the problem is that the rads.stackoverflow.net server is (at the very least) down...

Comment: Works for me.. Could have been a temporary outage.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed now. It turns out [the hosts file I use](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/) redirects rads.stackoverflow.net to 127.0.0.1. Nothing to see here... carry on!